# iOS ExternalAccessory Framework - "External Exception 0" while opening session

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I need to connect to a Bluetooth device (which is MFi certified) on iOS. Unfortunately Embarcadero has not imported External Accessory framework header files to Delphi units, but I thought perhaps I can take a look at `iOSapi.Foundation.pas` and do the conversion myself. External Accessory framework consists of 7 header files:

- `EAAccessory.h`
- `EAAccessoryManager.h`
- `EASession.h`
- `EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessory.h`
- `EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser.h`
- `ExternalAccessory.h`
- `ExternalAccessoryDefines.h`

Because my device uses Bluetooth, I did not import WiFi header files.

Here's my `uEAAccessoryManager.pas`, `uEAAccessory.pas`, and `uEASession.pas`:

Accessory Manager:

```
unit uEAAccessoryManager;

interface

uses
  Macapi.ObjectiveC,
  iOSapi.Foundation;

type
  EABluetoothAccessoryPickerCompletion = procedure(error: Pointer) of object;

type
  EAAccessoryManager = interface(NSObject)
    ['{C7D9DF32-44D2-4190-8202-801318FF57D9}']
    procedure showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter(predicate: NSPredicate; completion: EABluetoothAccessoryPickerCompletion); cdecl;
    procedure registerForLocalNotifications; cdecl;
    procedure unregisterForLocalNotifications; cdecl;
    function connectedAccessories: NSArray; cdecl;
  end;

  EAAccessoryManagerClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
    ['{015D15E4-6CDF-4117-A398-EC1DB11C9AEA}']
    function sharedAccessoryManager: Pointer; cdecl;
  end;

  TEAAccessoryManager = class(TOCGenericImport<EAAccessoryManagerClass, EAAccessoryManager>)
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Accessory

```
unit uEAAccessory;

interface

uses
  Macapi.ObjectiveC,
  iOSapi.Foundation,
  iOSapi.CocoaTypes;

type
  EAAccessory = interface(NSObject)
    ['{1DF56B17-AE6A-4CDC-A8F5-DB35F52535BE}']
    function connected: Boolean; cdecl;
    function connectionID: NSUInteger; cdecl;
    function manufacturer: NSString; cdecl;
    function name: NSString; cdecl;
    function modelNumber: NSString; cdecl;
    function serialNumber: NSString; cdecl;
    function firmwareRevision: NSString; cdecl;
    function hardwareRevision: NSString; cdecl;
    function protocolStrings: NSArray; cdecl;
    function id: Pointer; cdecl;
    procedure setID(id: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;

  EAAccessoryClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
    ['{AF265097-4A5A-4055-8B04-56A438354EA7}']
  end;

  TEAAccessory = class(TOCGenericImport<EAAccessoryClass, EAAccessory>)
  end;

  EAAccessoryDelegate = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{CF8586FA-20B1-4D1F-96AE-F96A3BC70556}']
    procedure accessoryDidDisconnect(accessory: EAAccessory); cdecl;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Session:

```
unit uEASession;

interface

uses
  Macapi.ObjectiveC,
  iOSapi.Foundation,
  iOSapi.CocoaTypes;

type
  EASession = interface(NSObject)
    ['{25D62FB5-EB6F-47BD-86D9-D31017D99900}']
    function accessory: Pointer; cdecl;
    function protocolString: NSString; cdecl;
    function inputStream: NSInputStream; cdecl;
    function outputStream: NSOutputStream; cdecl;
    function initWithAccessory(accessory: Pointer; protocolString: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
  end;

  EASessionClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
    ['{CA3F3621-E688-43BE-83CF-5580045E378C}']
  end;

  TEASession = class(TOCGenericImport<EASessionClass, EASession>)
  end;

implementation

end.
```

I can get the list of connected devices, and get information about a device with something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ListPairedDevices;
var
  i: Integer;
  FPairedDevices: NSArray;
begin
  lBDevices.Clear; // TListBox

  FPairedDevices := TEAAccessoryManager.Wrap(TEAAccessoryManager.OCClass.sharedAccessoryManager).connectedAccessories;
  for i := 0 to FPairedDevices.count - 1 do
    lBDevices.Items.Add(NSStrToStr(TEAAccessory.Wrap(FPairedDevices.objectAtIndex(i)).name));
end;
```

But when I want to open a session, I get "External Exception 0" on my iPhone 4 at the call to `initWithAccessory()`. Here's my code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.SendData;
var
  p, p1, p2: Pointer;
  b: array of Byte;
begin
  p := TEAAccessoryManager.Wrap(TEAAccessoryManager.OCClass.sharedAccessoryManager).connectedAccessories.objectAtIndex(lBDevices.ItemIndex);
  AEAAccessory := TEAAccessory.Wrap(p);
  p1 := (AEAAccessory as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
  p2 := (StrToNSStr('MFi.protocol.name.here.can.not.disclose.due.to.NDA') as ILocalObject).GetObjectID;
  p := TEASession.Alloc.initWithAccessory(p1, p2); // EXCEPTION HERE
  AEASession := TEASession.Wrap(p);
  SetLength(b, 1);
  b[0] := 5;
  AEASession.outputStream.write(@b[0], 1);
  Sleep(100);
  AEASession.inputStream.read(@b[0], 1);
  if b[0] = 6 then
    ShowMessage('ACK received!');
end;
```

So, is there something wrong with my translation of `EASession.h`?

Comment: I'm unable to make your ListPairedDevices code work in Delphi 10 Seattle. It jumps right past the for loop (i.e. it doesn't even evaluate the count property), and I've no idea why.

Comment: @DaveNottage Are you sure there are devices paired with your device?

Comment: Yes, they're definitely paired, since iOS shows the paired devices on the Bluetooth screen

Comment: @DaveNottage Well I can offer no help then, because on my iPhone 4 list of paired devices is shown